# value not encrytpting while calling direct method in java springbbot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have update patient api in my code, when direct api call is triggered it will update and insert encrypted data in DataBase BUT if I'm calling updatepatient method directly then it is not encrypting patient record only updating and storing in DB without encryption.

Here is encryption decryption logic in my code:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class PatientListener extends EntityEventListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void encryptRecord(Patient pc) {
        if (pc.getIsEncrypted()) {
            return;
        }
        EncryptDecryptService encryptDecryptService = determineEncryptionKey(pc);
        pc.setFirstName(encryptDecryptService.encryptString(pc.getFirstName()));
        ...
        pc.setIsEncrypted(true);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void encryptRecordAfterUpdate(Patient pc) {
        if (pc.getIsEncrypted()) {
            return;
        }
        EncryptDecryptService encryptDecryptService = determineEncryptionKey(pc);
        pc.setFirstName(encryptDecryptService.encryptString(pc.getFirstName()));
        ...
        pc.setIsEncrypted(true);
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void decryptRecord(Patient pc) {
        if (pc.getIsDecrypted()) {
            return;
        }
        EncryptDecryptService encryptDecryptService = determineEncryptionKey(pc);
        pc.setFirstName(encryptDecryptService.decryptString(pc.getFirstName()));
        ...
        pc.setIsDecrypted(true);
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling updatePatient method

```
@Override
    public CustomResponse updatePatient(RequestDto RequestDto) {
        CustomResponse customResponse = new CustomResponse();

        try {
           .
           .
           .
                if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(isMrgPatientUpdated.getFirst())) {
                  .
                  .
                    if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(isMrgPatientUpdated.getSecond())){
                        log.info("demographics are updated for the mrgPatientId : "+patientMrgId);
                        mrg2PatientService.updateByMrgDemographics(patientMrgId,RequestDto ,mrgId);
                    }
                    customResponse.setStatus(1);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("An unexpected error occurred: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new PatientServiceException("An unexpected error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return customResponse;
    }
```

UpdatePatient Method

```
 @Override
    public String updateByMrgPatient(UpdatePatientRequestDto updatePatientRequest, String patientId, int orgId, UpdateInitiatedTypeEnum updateInitiatedTypeEnum, String updateFrom){

        List<String> response = validateMandatoryFields(updatePatientRequest, orgId,updateFrom);
        if (!response.isEmpty()) {
            throw new PatientManagementException("Validation failed, fields missing or invalid: " + response);
        }

        Patient patient = patientRepo.findByPatientId(patientId);
        if (Patient == null) {
            throw new PatientManagementException("Patient with the given patientId is not found.");
        }

        updatePatient(updatePatientRequest, patient,orgId);

        publishEvent(patient,updateInitiatedTypeEnum);

        return patient.getPatientId();
    }

    @Transactional
    private void updatePatient(UpdatePatientRequestDto updatePatientRequest, Patient patient, int orgId) {
        boolean result = patientDetailsService.updatePatientDetails(updatePatientRequest, oasPatient);
        if (result) {
            patient.setUpdatedBy(updatePatientRequest.getUserId());
            patient.setUpdatedByUserType(updatePatientRequest.getUserType());
        }
        patientContactService.updateContactDetails(updatePatientRequest, oasPatient, result);
        }
```

why does it not encrypting record while calling updatePatient method directly in service Class

Comment: @Transactional annotation is important here can you put it to other method.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I have kept it on updatePatient but still it is not encrypting, can you pls confirm on which method it should keep

Comment: Transactional annotation does not work on private methods

Comment: You have to add to public method and it has to proxied by spring

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I noticed my repository method findByPatientId present in updateByMrgPatient() is also returning encrypted data but if call is going through api then it is returning decrypted data, got to know this with debugging

Answer (score 0):

Private methods can not open transaction because spring needs to use proxy on it and it is not possible. In your scenario just make method public and call from service class.

```
    @Transactional
    public void updatePatient(UpdatePatientRequestDto updatePatientRequest, Patient patient, int orgId) {
        boolean result = patientDetailsService.updatePatientDetails(updatePatientRequest, oasPatient);
        if (result) {
            patient.setUpdatedBy(updatePatientRequest.getUserId());
            patient.setUpdatedByUserType(updatePatientRequest.getUserType());
        }
        patientContactService.updateContactDetails(updatePatientRequest, oasPatient, result);
    }


    service.updatePatient(...)
```

Comment: I noticed my repository method findByPatientId present in updateByMrgPatient() is also returning encrypted data but if call is going through api then it is returning decrypted data, got to know this with debugging